# how do i deploy mobicents to glassfish v3

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, glassfish, jain-sip

is anyone using Mobicents with Glassfish in place of JBoss? how do i deploy mobicents to glassfish v3?

Comment: -1.. why? if nobody know the answer than vote down? what a nice place hah... awesome!!!!!!! and this is useful question... i think i will find the answer famous stackoverflow. i was wrong.. i will close my account. thanks to nothing...

Comment: It might help if you can post what you've attempted so far. The question in its current form implies that you haven't put in effort and can be interpreted as impolite by certain people. Disclaimer: I haven't downvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Mobicents is composed of multiple containers/projects Sip Servlets, JAIN SLEE, Media Server, Diameter, SIP Presence Service, what do you want to use exactly on top of Glassfish ?

If you want to deploy Sip Servlets to Glassfish this is not currently possible but it shouldn't be hard. Some refactoring will be needed but this can be done but won't be supported with commercial support from Red Hat, just by the community.

Open an issue here http://code.google.com/p/mobicents/issues/entry if you are interested in it and give as much details on what you want as possible

Comment: first of all i will use mobicents sip servlets. sip servlet is only i need right now. other features not required for now but might be..   i will open an issue... thanks.